# Why aren't mods using their super votes more often to close off-topic/unclear/duplicate posts?

Tags: discussion, support, moderators, vote-to-close, moderation

This question which seems more like a description of a social problem than an objective question has received only 2 close-votes so far:

> [marriage mantras of Hindus.,and DISTINCTION BETWEEN MARRIED AND UNMARRIED PERSONS IN SOCIETY](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40204/marriage-mantras-of-hindus-and-distinction-between-married-and-unmarried-in-soc)

A mod clears the bounty and now the bounty has been started again with [almost no changes](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/40204/revisions) making the question objective.

> 2020-05-02 16:58:34Z  `notice added`  user26375   Canonical answer required
>
> 2020-05-02 18:14:43Z  `comment added` Pandya♦ **Question is not clear**. It looks like you're asking for personal advice which is off-topic here. Go though help center. **Bounty has been removed**.
>
> 2020-05-02 18:17:39Z  `notice removed`    Pandya♦
>
> 2020-05-02 19:23:11Z  **`bounty started`**    user26375
>
> 2020-05-02 19:23:11Z  `notice added`  user26375   Authoritative reference needed

If the mod thought the question was not clear, why wasn't the post immediately closed when the bounty was removed?

Other posts which could use a mod super-vote:

> - [Why and when did Hindu's start eating non-veg](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40177/why-and-when-did-hindus-start-eating-non-veg)
> - [When Arjuna defeated all the Kuru warriors in the Virat war, then why did he kill them through deceit in the Kurukshetra war?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40382/when-arjuna-defeated-all-the-kuru-warriors-in-the-virat-war-then-why-did-he-kil)
> - [Do I need initiation to say a beeja/bija mantra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40454/do-i-need-initiation-to-say-a-beeja-bija-mantra)