# What should be the action on a question which has more than one querries and some of them are duplicates of already existing questions?

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close, specific-question, exact-duplicates

I was talking about this question: [Was Vivekananda a proponent of birth-based caste-system or the guṇa-based?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42419/was-vivekananda-a-proponent-of-birth-based-caste-system-or-the-gun%CC%A3a-based)

The title question appears to me as a duplicate of the following question: [Is there any explicit writing by Swami Vivekananda on his psychological theory of Varna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26688/is-there-any-explicit-writing-by-swami-vivekananda-on-his-psychological-theory-o)

The body of the question has two sub-questions, the first one of which is "Did he reject smṛtis such as Manu which seem to advocate birth-based varṇāśrama?", which appears to me as a duplicate of : [Does Neo-Vedanta reject Dharma Shastras? If so, why?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31930/does-neo-vedanta-reject-dharma-shastras-if-so-why/32325#32325)

Only the second question found in the body viz: "How did he interpret the Puruṣa-sūkta verse brāhmaṇo 'sya mukham ... padbhyāṃ śūdro ajāyata (brāhmaṇa was born from Puruṣa's mouth ... śūdra from his feet)?" appears to be a new one (not already asked on the site).

In this particular case or in such cases, in general, how should we go about closing the question or exactly how should we act?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We [have a feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/260388) of adding more than one duplicate links in the "closed as duplicate" post-notice. So, if question can be closed as duplicate of more than one question, it is fine to cast duplicate votes but if question body have a query which is not already answered/asked e.g what you've mentioned in the question:

> How did he interpret the Puruṣa-sūkta verse brāhmaṇo 'sya mukham ... padbhyāṃ śūdro ajāyata (brāhmaṇa was born from Puruṣa's mouth ... śūdra from his feet)?

Then closing as duplicate will not work properly. So, the proper action would be casting a "Needs more focus" reasoned close vote and adding comment underneath the question explaining the issue.

Comment: Can you please explain what part of my question needs focus? The whole focus of the question is Vivekananda's take on caste-system. I don't see how it can be improved further. Each of the sub-questions has already been answered by someone.

Comment: From [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) Help article: "Needs more focus - *if your question has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct)*, then it probably needs to be more focused to be successful in our format." - so this is meant for vague/subjective questions, where there can be multiple correct answers. My question doesn't fall under this category.

Comment: "adding comment underneath the question explaining the issue" - I don't see a comment from you under the question explaining the closure/use of your supervote...

Comment: Okay understood .. but in the past, I have seen people trying to close such Qs as duplicate if one of the sub-questions turns out to be a duplicate. People tried it on my Q too.

Comment: @sv. "Needs more focus" means "This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."

Comment: @Rickross which post of your? Share the link.

Comment: "This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only." - you are missing the point and selectively quoting Help Center to defend your supervote. It clearly says, "Avoid asking multiple **distinct** questions at once." - when all sub-questions are closely related, this doesn't apply. Please understand the difference between 'multiple closely-connected sub-questions' and 'multiple distinct questions'. I cannot explain you any further.

Comment: Besides, I don't understand the urgency at which you closed the question using a supervote when the community is still reviewing it.

Comment: @sv. When a moderator is sure, s/he can cast close/reopen votes.

Comment: Sure, but you need to realize that you are using a supervote, so a comment under the question would've been helpful. To quote from the [Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/): "**Whenever possible, try to leave frequent comments on posts where you’ve taken (or considered taking) a moderator action, explaining the reasoning.**"

Comment: @sv. Sure. [Done](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42419/was-vivekananda-a-proponent-of-birth-based-caste-system-or-the-gun%CC%A3a-based#comment131220_42419)!

Comment: I just noticed this question ([What are the Agama scriptures? Are they related to Shruti/Vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12282/2995)) asked by you which has several sub-questions. Should it be closed as 'needs more focus' as well?

Comment: @sv. Hmm... will continue further discussion tomorrow; good night.

Comment: @Pandya It was an old post of mine. The question has 2 sub-questions. Couple of users thought that one of those sub-Q was a duplicate. But eventually my Q was not closed as apart from those 2 users no one else thought likewise.

Comment: @Pandya IMO the real problem with the Q I'm discussing here is that it is more or less duplicate. The title Q is clearly a duplicate. Even one of the sub-Qs is a duplicate. Only way to salvage it is to stick with the Purusha Sukta query.

Comment: @sv. You yourself [was urging the Mods to use their super votes more often](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1892/why-arent-mods-using-their-super-votes-more-often-to-close-off-topic-unclear-du) but now when they have actually started doing it you have problems with it too.

Comment: LOL, if you bothered to read the whole post, in [that post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1892) I listed 3 questions ([question 1](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/40177), [Qn 2](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/40382) and [Qn 3](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/40454)) which I thought could use a mod super-vote, I find it funny that no action was taken on those by any mods here and yet _magically_, the mods find my post interesting to get involved. @Rickross

Comment: @Pandya Can we please continue the discussion on [What are the Agama scriptures? Are they related to Shruti/Vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12282) - should be we closing all such questions as 'needs more focus'? Is this a bad way of asking questions?

Comment: @Rickross I forgot to add that two of my recent flags requesting mods to close obvious dup. questions have been rejected with the reason: "declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention". I don't understand this reject reason given that a mod here has used his supervote to close my question. This seems like a case of interpreting site rules according to one's convenience.

Comment: I find it funny that no action was taken on those by any mods here and yet magically, the mods find my post interesting to get involved ---- You can not decide when someone else should cast close votes on posts. It's a subjective personal decision. If they are sure they will, if they are not they won't. Very simple @sv.

Comment: "If they are sure they will, if they are not they won't" - I think it's due to lack of will. E.g., you can see the mod desperately trying to save [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/36391/revisions) on 'mlecchas' from closure/deletion.

Answer (score 0):

The question under discussion seems like it should be closed as "Needs more focus".

As you have noted, there are various subquestions in that single post, some of which have been asked and answered earlier, and at least one of which appears to be new. It would be beneficial if the post is broken down into multiple questions so that each of the them can be answered adequately. Asking new questions would also be better because it gives more space for the OP to expand on why the existing potential duplicates do not satisfactorily address their questions.

Note that the standard close reason "Needs more focus" has the description "This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only." This is exactly the problem the question is facing as it currently stands.

Comment: Thanks .. so if I close vote it as a duplicate will that be wrong?

Comment: I think it is possible for a mod or a gold tag-badge holder to edit in multiple duplicate links, so yes, closing as duplicate(s) might be a reasonable alternative. However, there is no gold tag-badge holder in any of the tags on that question, and (it seems to me based on browsing Meta discussions that) the mods on the site move a little slowly in their actions. So, closing as "Needs more focus" is probably the more reasonable and effective solution here.

Comment: Ok but the close reason "needs focus" was previously called "too broad" or something .. now to be frank I don't really think that the Q is too broad given the fact that the sub-questions are closely linked with a single topic. But thanks for your perspective.

Comment: There is an element of subjectivity when making such judgement calls, of course. I can see why someone could argue that the multiple questions are closely linked enough to justify leaving the question open. A consensus should be fine, in either direction.

Comment: I have accepted the other answer, although yours was posted earlier and both the answers say basically the same thing. Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: @Rickross Not at all, thanks for letting me know :)